# How can I end ncurses without ending the C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I've been trying to make an ncurses program that will end the ncurses mode at a certain point, and resume in normal terminal mode, but still keeping the program running.
Is it possible? `endwin();` ends the program.
Here is my code (don't worry about the functions, I made them before):

```
clear();
refresh();
endwin();
boxmessage("STEP 1");
consolewrite("Removing Popularity Contest...");
std::vector<std::string> removepak;
removepak.push_back("popularity-contest");
removepackages(removepak);
```

Comment: I've never used NCurses before, but have you tried invoking the executable from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing that (that's how I always did it).

Comment: I've haven't done enough curses to know how easy this is, but a possible alternate avenue would be to stay *in* ncurses, but simple cover the whole terminal with a window that just does line-wise, terminal-like interaction.

Comment: `endwin()` should do what you want. [this](https://gist.github.com/1431726) works fine for me.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. According to the documentation, endwin simply restores the terminal. The docs even state: "Anytime after the call to initscr, endwin() should be called before exiting." which to me indicates that `exit` is a separate thing.

Comment: What is `boxmessage`? Does it happen to be or to call an ncurses comand? Because if you ended ncurses, I'd not expect that to work. What happens if you just use `std::cout` at that point?

Comment: OK, I found the bug. It was just because I made a series of buttons, then I did the 'case: x' part, and I just didn't write the integer that calls the function correctly. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`endwin()` isn't terminating your program; something else must be doing so.

This program works correctly on my system (Ubuntu 11.04, g++ 4.5.2):

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    initscr();
    mvaddstr(10, 10, "Hello, world");
    refresh();
    sleep(4);
    endwin();
    std::cout << "DONE\n";
}
```

It clears the screen, prints "Hello, world" at the expected position, sleeps for 4 seconds, then restores the screen and prints "DONE".

As was mentioned in comments, if `boxmessage()` uses ncurses, it's not going to work after you call `endwin()`.

Try adding some code after `endwin()` that creates and writes to a file, just to verify that your program doesn't die right there.

**Update** (nearly 16 months later), quoting the OP's most recent comment:

> OK, I found the bug. It was just because I made a series of buttons,
>   then I did the 'case: x' part, and I just didn't write the integer
>   that calls the function correctly. Thanks for trying to help!